# xmppframework connection and disconnection management with eJaberd

Tags: ios, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am struggling with managing XMPPFramework connectivity and disconnectivity with server

1. I cant keep connection active with server for infinite period of
   time
2. I Disconnect XMPPStream from server when Application Goes
   to background and stays thee for 10 minutes
3. I am using
   XMPPStreamManagement so messages are NOT missing
4. pplication goes down and Stream Disconnects from server

Issue

After One to two disconnections and connections XMPPStream Stuck on Connecting even network is working fine. 
When App goes background I can see logs that Stream Did Disconnected from server successfully 
How shall I manage re-connection and Why is Stucks.

I am using StreamManagement and AutoPing on Server and in XMPPFramework

Answer (score 0):

Use

"- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket"
set
"xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;"

Add voip for UIBackgroundMode in your Info.plist.

Add

(BOOL)setKeepAliveTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout handler:(void (^)(void))keepAliveHandler

Comment: (BOOL)setKeepAliveTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout handler:(void (^)(void))keepAliveHandler  has been deprecated in latest iOS and VoIP is also enabled and xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES enabled before connecting the XMPPStream. Still same result